# Python 'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'min''

Tags: python, numpy, attributes, attributeerror

I'm trying to write something to apply the Scipy function for spline interpolation to an array of values. My code currently looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x=var
x1 = ([0.1,0.3,0.4])
y1 = [0.2,0.5,0.6]

new_length = 25
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

but when it gets to the line

```
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'min'
```

and so far googling etc has turned up nothing that I understand. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please try to keep questions to only a single question, your first (programming) question is acceptable on this site, however, your second (non-programming) question has nothing to do with StackOverflow, and should be asked on Superuser.

Comment: If you do `from scipy.interpolate import interp1d` you can simply call `interp1d(...)`.  If you _only_ have `import scipy as sp` you must call it as `sp.interpolate.interp1d(...)`  You don't need to do both, unless you want to call `interp1d(...)` alone as well as another function from `scipy` like `sp.interp()` without explicitly importing `from scipy import interp` and `from scipy.interpolate import interp1d`

Answer (score 11):

If this line

```
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
```

is generating the error message

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'min'
```

then `x` is a function, and functions (in general) don't have `min` attributes, so you can't call `some_function.min()`.  What is `x`?  In your code, you've only defined it as

```
x=var
```

I'm not sure what `var` is.  `var` isn't a default builtin in Python, but if it's a function, then either you've defined it yourself for some reason or you've picked it up from somewhere (say you're using Sage, or you did a star import like `from sympy import *` or something.)

[Update: since you say you're "using PyLab", probably `var` is `numpy.var` which has been imported into scope at startup in IPython.  I think you really mean "using IPython in `--pylab` mode.]

You also define `x1` and `y1`, but then your later code refers to `x` and `y`, so it sort of feels like this code is halfway between two functional states.

Now `numpy` arrays *do* have a `.min()` and `.max()` method, so this:

```
>>> x = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7])
>>> y = np.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9])
>>> new_length = 25
>>> new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
>>> new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)
```

would work.  Your test data won't because the interpolation needs at least 4 points, and you'd get

```
ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 4 entries
```

Comment: Fantastic - that all went in fine without giving me any error messages at all. With x = var I was trying to make x into a variable but that doesn't actually make any sense with regards to the rest of the code so I'm not sure why I was doing it! Thanks very much, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> Second question: how do I input more than one line of code at once? At the moment, if I try to copy the whole thing and then paste it into PyLab, it only inputs the top line of my code, so I have to paste the whole thing in one line at a time. How do I get round this?

Assuming you're in `ipython` called as `ipython --pylab` or something similar, then you can simply use [the `paste` magic command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#magic-functions).  Call it as `%paste` or simply `paste` if you haven't defined `paste` as another variable:

```
In [8]: paste
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x=var
x1 = ([0.1,0.3,0.4])
y1 = [0.2,0.5,0.6]

new_length = 25
new_x = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), new_length)
new_y = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(new_x)

## -- End pasted text --
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b4e41f59d719> in <module>()
      3 from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
      4 
----> 5 x=var
      6 x1 = ([0.1,0.3,0.4])
      7 y1 = [0.2,0.5,0.6]

NameError: name 'var' is not defined

In [9]:
```

Answer (score 2):

Change that line to:

```
new_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), new_length)
```

`min` and `max` are not attributes of lists, they are their own functions.

Comment: Thanks - fixed that. I now get 'TypeError: 'function' object is not interable'.

Comment: I think you want to run this on `x1` as I am not sure what `x=var` means. but `x1` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error when I called `timezone.now` instead of `timezone.now()`. I then tried to format the `DateTime` value that I was expecting. But it wasn't a `DateTime`; it was a function. This resulted in an error message about 'Month' not being an attribute of 'function'.

The fix was to simply add the parentheses after `now`. This called the `now` function and returned its result, instead of returning the `now function` object itself.

Silly mistake, I know. But not easy to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue.

My error was I named a variable and function name as same.

I corrected that and error vanished.

Answer (score -1):

Int's don't have a min() function but min() is a builtin function. You'll need to use min(x).